# Lua - Managing tables... Object Oriented?

Tags: oop, lua, lua-table

For a while now, I have been managing Lua tables via the use of functions and whatnot for character progress tracking. Lately, I've been reading more and more about OO methods and metatables, and I'm wondering if that is a better way to handle this. For instance, here's a breakdown of progress tracking:

When a character is first initialized, I do:

```
init_tracker(pname, reset)
```

which pulls a text file template of the starter database. This template breaks down the table as such:

```
Player Name {
  Exp {
   Several keys here, values as 0
  },
  Quests {
   Several keys here, values as 0
  },
  Campaigns {
   Several keys here, values as 0
  },
}
```

etc. There are other keys under the Player name, but that's a gist of what the table structure looks like. I keep track of yearly, monthly, weekly, daily, hourly, and per level stats that reset appropriately, as well as track their previous stats (last week, last year, last month, etc.). For that, I have functions that iterate through each table, copies to the last table, then resets the values on the current table.

Would it be better to use metatables and methods for this? For instance, should I be doing:

```
Player["Current"]:update()
```

with an update function as a method, rather than

```
for i, v in pairs(Player["Current"]) do
  Player["Last"][i] = v
  Player["Current"][i] = 0
end
```

(which, by the way, does not seem to work anymore, as it's always displaying 0)?

If I would be better off using OO, how would I structure that into what I have now?

Comment: Your example at the end is probably wrong. For one, `t["x"]:foo( )` is a syntax error – you'd do `t.x:foo( )` or instead of `t[k]:foo( )` you'd do `t[k].foo( t[k] )`. This may also be why your code broke – maybe you intended to say `Player[Last][i] = v` and not `Player["Last"][i] = v` (if `Last` is a variable) etc.?

Comment: No, Last isn't a variable in this case. Pretty much, it's `Player["Current"]["ExpGained"]`, `Player["Current"]["QPGained"]`, etc.... and `Player["Last"]["ExpGained"]`, `Player["Last"]["QPGained"]`, etc.... The example I put up there is because I'm still new to OOP in Lua, so I'm not used to the syntax yet.

Comment: Well, then you can just say `Player.Current.ExpGained`, `Player.Current.QPGained` etc. – that's more readable (and in that style, the `:` syntactic sugar will work.)